# Factors of polynomial not passing the Bezout's identity test

Tags: divisibility, factoring

When factoring $x^3 - 2x^2 - 4x - 8$ the result you get is $(x-2)(x^2 - 4)$ or $(x-2)^2 (x+2)$ , meaning  that the mentioned polynomial is divisible by each of these factors. When using the Bezout's identity regarding factoring polynomials backwards and plugging values ±2 into the polynomial, the result is never zero. Then how is it  possible for it to be divisible with both $(x-2)$ and $(x+2)$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is $\ (x-2)x^2 -4 (x+2)\ $ so $\ x-2\ $ is *not* a factor. Probably you made a sign error when pulling out the factor of $-4.\ $

Comment: I was reading the solution online and the author made a mistake which I failed to see. So... there isn't a way to factorize this polynome? Also, should I delete the post entirely, because it's no use ?

Comment: We know how to find the roots of a $3$rd degree polynomial, so yes you basically can factor it, however, they are really not pretty (we just don't know, and it has been proven to be impossible I believe, for degree over 5)

Comment: I usually factor 3rd degree poynomial in two steps. First, I find all the divisors of the last, coefficient-free part of the polynomial (in this case that's 8) and try (applying Bezout's identity) to plug them into P(x) one by one until I get zero. That way I know my polynomial is divisible by (x - n), where n is that divisor. Then, I do my division and get a quadratic polynomial, which I factor using the formulae for solving quadratic equasions. And that's how I get three factors of 3rd degree polynomial. But in this case, my method fails at step one. How could I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a mistake while pulling out factors.
The answer is: Bezout's identity works only when a polynomial has real number roots.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a remainder if you divide your polynomial by $X-2$:
$$X^3-2X^2-4X-8=(X-2)(X^2-4)-16$$

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the polynomial does not actually factor in that way. We have

$$(x-2)(x^2-4)=x^3-4x-2x^2+8=x^3-2x^2-4x\color{red}{+}8$$

Note that this is different because in this one we have $+8$ instead of $-8$, so it was not an issue with Bezout's identity, but rather with factoring.